# _POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_ Getting error to MD5 value missmatch

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

i'm trying to post fulfillment with the following code

I'm using json to convert it into xml as my json is

```
var ShipJson = {
                          "AmazonEnvelope": {
                                "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
                                "-xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation": "amznenvelope.xsd",
                                "Header": {
                                  "DocumentVersion": "1.01",
                                  "MerchantIdentifier": MRChID
                                },
                                "MessageType": "OrderFulfillment",
                                "Message": {
                                  "MessageID": "1",                           
                                  "OrderFulfillment": {
                                     "MerchantOrderID" : OrderId,
                                     "MerchantFulfillmentID":"1234567",
                                     "FulfillmentDate": "2017-06-20T00:36:33-08:00",
                                    "FulfillmentData": {
                                      "CarrierName": "UPS",
                                      "ShippingMethod": "Second Day",
                                      "ShipperTrackingNumber": "1234567890"
                                    },
                                    "Item": {
                                      "MerchantOrderItemID":"1234567",
                                      "MerchantFulfillmentItemID": "1234567",
                                      "Quantity": "2"
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            };
```

this json i'm converting into xml and then into bae64-md5 using crypto js

```
            var xml = cm.util.Formatter.json2xml(ShipJson);

            var ContentMD5Value = CryptoJS.MD5(xml,true);
            var MD5Base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(ContentMD5Value);
                var that = this;
                var uri = "/";
                var today = new Date();
                time = today.toISOString();
                var parameters = {
                    "AWSAccessKeyId":;kjuhjfgd, 
                    "Action":"SubmitFeed",
                    "ContentMD5Value": MD5Base64,
                    "FeedType":"_POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_",
                    "Merchant":lgtjljtd,
                    "PurgeAndReplace":"false",
                    "SignatureMethod":"HmacSHA256",
                    "SignatureVersion":"2", 
                    "Timestamp": time,
                    "Version":"2009-01-01"

                };

            var parameters1 = $.param(parameters);
                var messageToEncrypt =  sap.ui.getCore.method+"\n"+sap.ui.getCore.host+"\n"+ uri +"\n"+parameters1;
                var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(messageToEncrypt, sap.ui.getCore().secreteKey);
                var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);

                var parameters100 = {
                        "AWSAccessKeyId":jhfjfzhkhgs,   
                        "Action":"SubmitFeed",
                        "Merchant":gjdhjdgfzgd,
                        "SignatureVersion":"2", 
                        "Timestamp": time,
                        "Version":"2009-01-01",
                        "ContentMD5Value": MD5Base64,
                        "Signature":hashInBase64,
                        "SignatureMethod":"HmacSHA256",
                        "FeedType":"_POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_",
                        "PurgeAndReplace":"false"

                    };

                var parameters101 = $.param( parameters100 );

                var mwsRequest = sap.ui.getCore.protocol+"://"+sap.ui.getCore.host;


                   var odatamodel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(mwsRequest, {
                     headers: {
                         "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"

                     }
                    });
                    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(odatamodel);      

                    OData.request({
                            requestUri: mwsRequest+ "/?" + parameters101,
                            method: "POST",
                            headers: {

                            },
                            data: {}

                        },
                        function(data, response) {

                        },
                        function(err,response) {


                            var res = err.response.body;    
                }
                    );
```

But i'm getting error with MD5Content Value missmatch

```
"<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>ContentMD5DoesNotMatch</Code><Message>the Content-MD5 HTTP header you passed for your feed did not match the Content-MD5 we calculated for your feed</Message><Detail/></Error><RequestID>43637524-65a0-42be-bdfc-3d78290e8810</RequestID></ErrorResponse>"
```

please help me out am i following wrong method or am i missing something or my MD5 library is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are calculating the MD5 seems correct. You are, however sending `ContentMD5Value` as part of the request. I'm not sure if that is an accepted alternative, all code I've seen send a http header instead: `Content-MD5: stringWithMD5inBase64` along with `Content-Type: text/xml`.

I'm not sure what all that sap.ui stuff is doing (and I'm not really great with JavaScript), but I'm guessing you need to change the `headers` element in OData.request. But then again, I don't see you ever actually sending the contents of `xml`?